# How to show page number on page 1?

Tags: header-footer, numbering, ieeetran

I'm writing a technical paper to an IEEE conference, which requires the paper pages to be numbered, from what I understood. I'm using `\pagestyle{plain}`, which seems to work only from page 2 and on. The number on page 1 is not shown. Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[10pt, conference, compsocconf, letterpaper]{IEEEtran}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\begin{document}
\title {Paper title\\[-3.0ex]}
\maketitle
    text
\clearpage
    text
\clearpage
    text
\end{document}
```

How can I make the page number appear in *all* pages, including page 1?

Another question, to those familiar with the IEEEtran template: Is the page number 1 actually supposed to appear on the first page, as I'm suspecting?

Comment: You probably shouldn't do that, because it goes against the template.

Comment: Did you try inserting `\thispagestyle{plain}` immediately after `\maketitle`? Incidentally, I'm not familiar with the `IEEEtranv` document class. Did you mean to write `IEEEtran`?

Comment: Yes, I meant to write IEEEtran. Thanks for pointing that out, I just corrected it.

Comment: I would recommend against customizing the layout if you want to submit this to a conference. Adding `\thispagestyle{plain}` will indeed show the page number at the bottom, but if you look at the documentation you will find that page numbers are omitted in `conference` mode. Removing the `\\[-3.0ex]` after the title is also a good idea (try adding `\IEEEspecialpapernotice{(Invited Paper)}` and you'll see why).

Comment: @erik You should make than an answer to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend against customizing the layout if you want to submit this to a conference. Adding `\thispagestyle{plain}` will indeed show the page number at the bottom, but if you look at the documentation you will find that page numbers are omitted in conference mode. Removing the `\\[-3.0ex]` after the title is also a good idea (try adding `\IEEEspecialpapernotice{(Invited Paper)}` and you'll see why).